# Generating menu with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form where people can add or delete menus and options for those menus in order to generate a menu for a game. I need to be able to grab the value of the form data for each specific menu and the options for that menu, so my current idea is to have a variable put into the id of each menu and then a new variable into the id of each option. Each time they add a menu, that variable increases and each time they add an option for that menu, the variable specific to that menu increases. The problem is that if they add a ton of menus or options and then delete them, the number still increases and I could end up have menus and options with huge gaps between their id values.

Is there a way to do this with arrays? I'm not sure how much sense this is going to make if any, so let me rephrase:

Is there a way to make an array of elements?

I'm having a very hard time just trying to describe what I'm trying to do. Do any of you have AIM or another means of live chat?

Comment: Stackoverflow has a chat system, but you will need at least 20 reputations to participate there.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It pisses me off, but at the same time I understand it. They don't want new users spamming the chat, but how am I supposed to get 20 rep when I have questions?

Comment: Participate a lil' more in stackoverflow. It's not that hard to get reps here !!

Comment: Can you give an example or show some code — even pseudo code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure I understood correctly what that you are trying to do, but if I did this is my solution:

have jQuery `.size()` run every time someone deletes a menu or option, and then reassign the ID of each element with a `.each()` loop.
[jQuery size() page](http://api.jquery.com/size)